# How to calculate mean-square error(MSE) and PSNR values for edge detected images

Tags: matlab, edge-detection, canny-operator, error-detection

I am using the following code to find the mean square error of edge images with comparison to the reference edge image.

```
clc;    % Clear the command window.
close all;  % Close all figures (except those of imtool.)
clear;  % Erase all existing variables. Or clearvars if you want.
workspace;  % Make sure the workspace panel is showing.
format long g;
format compact;
fontSize = 20;


ReferenceImage = imread('F:\R\CT\0.5\0.5\2.jpg');
[rows columns] = size(ReferenceImage);

% Display the first image.
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imshow(ReferenceImage, []);
title('Reference image with Sigma 0.8 and Threshold 0', 'FontSize', fontSize);
set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize')); % Maximize figure.

% Get a second image by adding noise to the first image.
noisyImage = imread('F:\R\CT\0.5\0.5\3.jpg');


% Display the second image.
subplot(2, 2, 2);
imshow(noisyImage, []);
title('Noisy Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);

%------ PSNR CALCULATION ----------------------------------------------------------
% Now we have our two images and we can calculate the PSNR.
% First, calculate the "square error" image.
% Make sure they're cast to floating point so that we can get negative differences.
% Otherwise two uint8's that should subtract to give a negative number
% would get clipped to zero and not be negative.
squaredErrorImage = (double(ReferenceImage) - double(noisyImage)) .^ 2;
% Display the squared error image.
subplot(2, 2, 3);
imshow(squaredErrorImage, []);
title('Squared Error Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
% Sum the Squared Image and divide by the number of elements
% to get the Mean Squared Error.  It will be a scalar (a single number).
mse = sum(sum(squaredErrorImage)) / (rows * columns);
% Calculate PSNR (Peak Signal to Noise Ratio) from the MSE according to the formula.
PSNR = 10 * log10( 256^2 / mse);
% Alert user of the answer.
message = sprintf('The mean square error is %.2f.\nThe PSNR = %.2f', mse, PSNR);
msgbox(message);
```

However I get results like an attached image, But instead of getting the final single value, I am getting an error as,

```
Error in msgbox (line 59)
error(nargoutchk(0,1,nargout));
Error in error (line 49)
msgbox(message);
```

[image: Result of Error Image]

Comment: There is no problem with your code, even if your input image is RGB, where `mse` and `PSNR` are not scalar values, `msgbox` works as expected. If I give `msgbox` wrong input to force it to give me an error, it'll give me a much more informative error. Why don't you copy-paste the full error message here?

Comment: When I call `msgbox` with wrong input I get an error `Expected input to be one of these types: char, cell Instead its type was double. [...] Error in msgbox (line 62) [...]`. Your error message makes no sense. Why don't you print your variables to the command line, instead of a message box, to see if they're right? Let's start from there. In your other question I suggested you read the MATLAB tutorial. Now I'm also suggesting you learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo. I made it display instead of calling msgbox and it works fine. Yes, I am reading tutorials and watching related videos to learn. Thank you